# BootstrapDialog.alert() not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, dialog, bootstrap-dialog

I am using the following code to show a BootstrapDialog and its not showing up
Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>dialog box example</title>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <input type="button"  value="button1" class="btn btn-info" onclick="showmes();">


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function showmes() {
        BootstrapDialog.show(typeof(BootstrapDialog)); //.alert('I want banana!');
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

BootstrapDialog is not part of the bootstrap library, it is a part from an [external javascript library](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog) built on top of bootstrap.

Therefore, you must include the `bootstrap-dialog.js` and the `bootstrap-dialog.min.css` (or respectively minimal versions). You can build the files yourself following the readme, or get them from the js and css subfolders of the [dist](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/tree/master/dist) folder.